# Google Sheet consolidate data

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to consolidate the data from different sheets in the same File for Google Sheets. However, I get the following error:

```
Error
Array result was not expanded because it would override data in A3
```

Basically, I wanted it to get all the values within each sheet range and insert it into one sheet because re-entering the same data twice is very time consuming

Here is what I have tried that causes the error:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iS3hBtbkAyi5ql9V-6YwerQWXKx2ED8SR5bR3PY3Bm4/edit#gid=0", "Sheet2!A2:B30")
```

Comment: Well, it seems like cell A3 is not blank, hence the error...

Comment: What do you have in A3?

Comment: @Jerry Touché :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get those kind of errors is because you are importing a matiz of information that if shown will override data that you already have in your sheet.
What I recommend to solve this usually is to create a new sheet and make the import in a blank new sheet but if you are trying to consolidate 2 columns into 4(2 of each duplicating the data) make sure that you are giving the correct space between each other, for example I guess you will want to put the first import  in cell A1 and the second in C1. And if you are putting just one `IMPORTRANGE` formula in a sheet with data already there just make sure it won't overlap.

> This means your problem is basically information overlapped when
>   importing using `IMPORTRANGE` formula

Basic things to try to resolve the issue or find out a path to do it can be:

```
select cell A3 and push delete button.
```

Or

```
create a new sheet and try the formula again with an empty sheet.
```

Answer (score 0):

delete everything you have in cell **A3** or add a row between **A2** and **A3**

or use this formula:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1iS3hBtbkAyi5ql9V-6YwerQWXKx2ED8SR5bR3PY3Bm4", "Sheet3!A2:B2")
```